# how to get values of the values from the text boxes using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

This is the following code to get the values from the text boxes. the code displays the values simultaneously but I want to use **click binding so that my java script is invoked and the values are displayed.** Each time it display the values **it should also display the old values entered.**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>First name</td><td> <input type="text" class="inputs" id="first" data-bind="text: $data" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last name</td><td> <input type="text" class="inputs" id="Text1" data-bind="text: $data" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Dob</td><td> <input type="text" class="inputs" id="Text2" data-bind="text: $data" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description</td><td> <textarea rows="5" cols="17" class="inputs" id="Text3" data-bind="text: $data"></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="button" value="submit" onclick="AppViewModel()" /></td></tr>
    </table>

    <h2>The values entered will be</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>First Name </td><td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="first" data-bind="value: foobar; valueUpdate: 'keyup'"></input></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name </td><td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="Text4" data-bind="value: good; valueUpdate: 'keyup'" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Dob</td><td> <input type="text" class="inputs" id="Text5" data-bind="value: bad; valueUpdate: 'keyup'" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description</td><td> <textarea rows="5" cols="16" class="inputs" id="Text6" data-bind="value: ugly; valueUpdate: 'keyup'"></textarea></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    function AppViewModel() {

        this.foobar = ko.observable('');
        this.good = ko.observable('');
        this.bad = ko.observable('');
        this.ugly = ko.observable('');
        var val = document.getElementById('first').value;

        if (!val.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/ || val == "")) {
            alert('Please fill the boxes correctly');

            return false;
        }
        var last = document.getElementById('Text1').value;

        if (!last.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/ || val == "")) {
            alert('Please fill the boxes correctly');
            myform.last.focus();
            return false;
        }


        var myDate = document.getElementById('Text2').value;
        var myDatePattern = /^[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[0|1]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[0-9]{4}$/;
        var validFormat = myDatePattern.test(myDate);

        if (validFormat == true) {

            var myDay = myDate.substring(0, 2);
            var myMonth = myDate.substring(3, 5);
            var myYear = myDate.substring(6, 10);

            if (myDay > 31 | myDay < 1) {
                alert('You have entered an invalid day');
                var day = false;
            }
            else {
                var day = true
            };

            if (myMonth > 12 | myMonth < 1) {
                alert('You have entered an invalid month');
                var month = false;
            }
            else {
                var month = true
            };

            var now = new Date();
            if (myYear > now) {
                alert('You have entered an invalid year. Please use a date before today');
                var year = false;
            }
            else {
                var year = true
            };

            if (day == false | month == false | year == false) {
                alert('You have entered an invalid date format');
            };

        }


    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
```

please do help.

Comment: I really can't understand what you're asking... Try create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `$data` is relevant to the binding context, if your markup is not inside a `with` or `foreach` then `$data` will probably be your whole `AppViewModel`... also the `text` binding is not meant for `input` elements I dont think.. not sure what you are trying to do but KO tracks all changes you make to an observable for you.. so if your trying to store the value before the observable was changed you should look at the `beforeChange` examples here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html